# Passing Data to view in a Redirect request to prevent double submission

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am trying to prevent double submission through the back button in a simple voting application

I was doing this before. After voting it returns this view

```
return View::make('votes.votesresults')->with('candidates',$candidates)->with('count',$count);
```

This passes two variables to `votesresult` view but unfortunately if someone clicks the back button they can resubmit their votes. I looked around and came across the PRG pattern. Am supposed to use a redirect to prevent this. So i tried this

```
    return Redirect::route('votes.votesresults')->with('candidates',$candidates)->with('count',$count);
```

Here are my controllers

```
public function votesuccess()
{ 

 $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required'
        );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('votes/index')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    } else {
        // store

        $vote = new Vote;
        $candidates = Candidate::all();

        $candidate_id =Input::get('name');
        $candidate = Candidate::find($candidate_id);

        $vote = $candidate->votes()->save($vote);

        //$count = DB::table('votes')->where('candidate_id','=','$candidate_id')->count();
        $count =  DB::table('votes')->count();



        // redirect
        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully Cast your vote!');
       //return View::make('votes.voteresults')->with('candidates', $candidates)->with('count',$count);
       return Redirect::route('voteresults')->with('candidates', $candidates)->with('count',$count);


    }
}

public function voteresult()
{  
    $candidates = Candidate::all();


    return View::make('votes.voteresults');

}
```

My routes are like this

```
Route::post('votesuccess', array('as' => 'votesuccess',   'uses'=>'VoteController@votesuccess'));
Route::get('voteresults', array('as' => 'voteresults', 'uses'=>'VoteController@voteresult'));
```

This does not work because it returns `undefined variable: candidates`. My results view requires these variables. So how do I implement the PRG pattern correctly such that I prevent double submission while being able to pass data to my view

Comment: Probably not the issue but you have spelling mistake: `->wit('count',$count);`. Can you show your related controller actions code?

Comment: Shouldn't you be preventing double voting in the back-end? If a user tries to vote twice, then an error may be displayed.

Comment: @JofryHS Added controllers and routes maybe you can throw some light

Comment: Can you leave out the `candidates` and see if the `count` variable is available after the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting to the route named `voteresults`, which is handled by the `voteresult` function and not the `votesuccess` function.

In your `votesuccess` function, you should load the view and include the `candidates` variable in that view. You can access the `candidates` variable stored in the session by using `Session::get('candidates')`.

Comment: doesn't seem to work. Someone can still go back and resubmit a vote.Any other ideas about how to mitigate this.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see you voter results view to see what's going on there, and where/how you've put in logic to avoid duplicate submission. Are you concerned about accidental re-submissions, or just multiple submissions from the same user? If the latter, then you would need to build in some logic that limits a user to only 1 vote. You could do this by check if the user has a related vote.

```
if ( ! $candidate->votes() ) {
    // no votes exist, proceed with storing vote
}
```

Below is you controller refactored a bit:

```
public function votesuccess()
{ 

    $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required'
        );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back('votes/index')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    } else {
        // store
        $candidate = Candidate::find(Input::get('name'));
        $vote = $candidate->votes()->save(new Vote);


        // redirect
        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully Cast your vote!');
        return Redirect::route('voteresults');
    }
}

public function voteresult()
{  
    $candidates = Candidate::all();
    $count =  DB::table('votes')->count();

    return View::make('votes.voteresults', compact('candidates', 'count'));

}
```